# why performance degradation when we return multiple value vs single value in python?

Tags: python

Python support multiple return but it has performance issue.can you explain why ?

```py
def add1(a,b):
    return a+b
def add2(a,b):
    return a+b
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('[func(1,1) for func in (add1,add2)]', globals=globals()))
```

times while diff execution:
0.5730050599668175,0.58586961904075,
0.5807652469957247

```py
def add1(a,b):
    return a+b, True
def add2(a,b):
    return a+b, True
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('[func(1,1) for func in (add1,add2)]', globals=globals()))
```

times while diff execution:
0.6645272029563785, 0.6714418820338324, 0.6890694650355726

Comment: Why don't test it yourself? Use timeit and check if there is a peformance impact

Comment: if yes then why i will don't get while comparing time i want to know internal operations. i saw many stack overflow question but won't find the ans so i raise it

Comment: "if yes then" - you should first try and see if there really is a relevant performance problem in such a case. Until this has been established, there isn't that much reason to discuss the underlying, probably implementation dependant mechanisms.

Comment: Technically speaking you are not returning multiple values. You are returning a single object. A tuple

Comment: Strictly speaking, Python doesn't support multiple return types. ``return a, b`` is the syntax for an expression that provides a tuple, and for returning what the expression provided. That's *more* work than just providing one thing – whether it's a "performance issue" cannot be said in general (though in most cases it's not).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi in above small operation the diff is very high

Comment: @DhavalkumarPrajapati Your functions do *practically nothing* and still only have less than 20% difference. If your program consists only of functions that do practically nothing, the 20% difference from ``return`` is the least of your worries. But these micro-benchmarks are *exactly* why it's futile to discuss the question in it's current state – it would require way too much background to put the raw numbers into context.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi just i want to know should i avoid for returning multiple value when its possible ?

Comment: No. The overhead is negligible in any realistic program.

Comment: You may want to avoid it (where possible, as you state), but certainly not for performance reasons. Maybe for the sake of readability or code simplicity. But then again, lots of battle-tested functions and frameworks do it, so it is  definitely not an anti-pattern.

Comment: @DhavalkumarPrajapati, "_just i want to know should i avoid for returning multiple value when its possible_". That wasn't your question. Your question was why returning multiple values is slower than returning one value and that was explained in the comments above. Please make sure you formulate your question correctly, otherwise the answers won't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the Pythonic answer is *just do not care*.

Early low level optimisation is generally considered as a bad practice because it leads to code harder to read and maintain at a moment where additions and refactoring are to be expected.

If you are in a use case where you have identified a bottleneck or for any reason have a strong requirement for speeding up a small piece of code, it is generally much more efficient to code that part in C language (or your underlying platform language if not using CPython). If you have ever used numpy, you know that there are orders of magnitude between a native Python loop and the same one using the optimized (read coded in C) numpy version.

Testing that for a better understanding of the internals of the Python interpretor is not bad (improving own knowledge can never be). But you must be aware that the next step should be to dive in the sources of the interpretor to understand the real cause. Only 10% is not a very important difference and without a further analyzis I would not be too confident in the *reproductibility*.